# XSLT how to write time from 00 to 23:00

Tags: php, html, xslt

This are my rows. I have 24 rows for 24 hours. I create an loop in xslt.

```
<xsl:variable name="n-rows" select="24"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <xsl:call-template name="td-recursive"/>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="td-recursive">
  <xsl:param name="index" select="1"/>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="$index"/>
  </td>
  <xsl:if test="$index &lt; $n-rows">
    <xsl:call-template name="td-recursive">
      <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

but here

```
<xsl:value-of select="$index"/>
```

I want to write hours and not numbers like 00:00, 01:00 to 23:00

How can I write hours in XSLT with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($index,'00'),':00')"/>
```

Your loop goes from 1 to 24, if you want the first hour to be 00:00 and the last one to be 23:00 you need to also subtract 1:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($index - 1,'00'),':00')"/>
```

or modify the loop